# Add percentage column to panda dataframe with percent sign

Tags: python, excel, pandas

For the below excel which will be used as panda dataframe

```
   df['% '] = (df['Code Lines'] / df['Code Lines'].sum())*100
```

Output comes

```
Language    # of Files  Blank Lines Comment Lines   Code Lines   % 
C++            15         66         35               354      3.064935065
C/C++ Header    1         3          7                 4       0.034632035
Markdown        6         73         0                142      1.229437229
Python         110        1998      2086              4982     43.13419913
Tcl/Tk          1         14         18               273      2.363636364
YAML            1          0         6                 20      0.173160173
Total          134        2154      2152                5775    50
```

I am trying to get % column should be of only 2 decimal places with a percent sign

Something like this

```
Language    # of Files  Blank Lines Comment Lines   Code Lines   % 
C++            15         66         35               354      3.06%
C/C++ Header    1         3          7                 4       0.03%
Markdown        6         73         0                142      1.22%
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html), convert to strings and add `%`:

```
df['%'] = ((df['Code Lines'] / df['Code Lines'].sum())*100).round(2).astype(str) + '%'
```

Comment: can I convert back that to number as I exported to excel .I am getting warning "Number stored as text"